# How can I define a very large matrix efficiently?

Tags: matrix

Here's a 7x7 matrix:

```
(matrix = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 
     1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, -3, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, -4, 0, 
     0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -5, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
     1, -6}}) // MatrixForm
```

The matrix looks like this:

[image]

How can I define the 100x100 equivalent of this matrix efficiently without having to manually type out every element? [The documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstructingMatrices.html) gives some ideas, but although there's certainly an order in this matrix, it's not something that translates easily (at all?) to the commands used in the documentation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
size = 7;
Table[Which[i == 1, 1, i > j, 1, i == j, -i + 1, True, 0], {i, size}, {j, size}]
```

Comment: Worked very well, now I'll have to understand your syntax =)

Comment: You might be interested in a tweak to your method explained in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

The question refers to efficiency, which might mean with respect to programming, performance, or both.  My guess is programming, but highlighting the performance strengths of *Mathematica* should promote learning the "*Mathematica* style" as it is sometimes referred to.

Timings on various approaches for `size = 100` (timing code given at the end):

- `0.008800` [@kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)
- `0.007000` [@Rohit Namjoshi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/58370/rohit-namjoshi), which can be improved to `0.00026`
- `0.000510` [@MikeY](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/47314/mikey), which can be improved to `0.000041` (best of all)
- `0.000047` [@MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999),
  (was never under `0.000042` but usually `0.000046` to `0.000048`)

My best solution:

```
size = 5;
matrix = 
 With[{r    = Range@size,
       zero = Developer`ToPackedArray@{0}},
    UnitStep[Outer[Plus, r, -r] + PadRight[ConstantArray[r, {1}], {size, size}]] - 
     DiagonalMatrix@PadRight[zero, size, r]
    ];
matrix // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Discussion

**`Table[]` vs. `Array[]`.**
The solution of **[@RohitNamjoshi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201348/4999)** can be improved by using `Array[]`. This involves turning the expression `e` into a function, which takes only wrapping the expression with `Function[{i, j}, e]` and removing `i` and `j` from the iterators:

```
Array[Function[{i, j},
    Which[i == 1, 1, i > j, 1, i == j, -i + 1, True, 0]
    ], {size, size}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.00039, Null}  *)
```

It can be sped up a little by compiling the function.  Compiling with or without `CompilationTarget -> "C"` affects `Table[]` and `Array[]` differently.  Compiling speeds up `Table[]` (`0.0039` sec.), but whether to C or not makes no perceptible difference.  Compiling to C speeds up `Array[]` slightly, but compiling to WVM the option *slows down* `Array[]` (`0.00091` sec.); I don't know why.

```
cf = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
   Which[
    i == 1, 1,
    i > j, 1,
    i == j, -i + 1,
    True, 0], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

Array[cf, {size, size}]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.00026, Null}  *)
```

**Vectorization vs. Compiling.**
Many basic functions in *Mathematica* are *vectorized*: They work efficiently on [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).  Elementary functions, many linear algebra functions, some list manipulation functions (esp. functions operating on rectangular arrays) are particularly efficient on packed arrays.  Other functions might "unpack" the array, which involves copying the packed array into the unpacked form.  This done internally but there are ways to tell (`On["Packing"]` and `` Developer`PackedArrayQ `` for instance); mainly it is invisible to the user except for a performance hit.  Usually, but not always, the vectorized functions are more efficient than compiled functions.  The solution of **[@MikeY](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201377/4999)** takes advantage of this up until `ones` and the use of `ArrayFlatten[]`, which unpacks its arguments to assemble the final matrix.  The reason `ArrayFlatten[]` unpacks is because one of the inputs, `ones`, is not packed.  It turns out that user-entered lists are not packed.  If we pack it, we get a great improvement in performance:

```
With[{n = size - 1},
   Block[{m1, m2, ones},
    m1 = LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {n, n}], -1];
    m2 = m1 - DiagonalMatrix[Range[n]];
    ones = Developer`ToPackedArray@{ConstantArray[1, n]};
    ArrayFlatten[{{1, ones}, {Transpose@ones, m2}}]
    ]]; // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.000041, Null}  *)
```

Using `ArrayPad[m2, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, 1]`, as suggested by @kglr, is about the same speed (the timings fluctuate around each other), even though it eliminates a line of code (for `ones`). But `ones` is just 1 x 100 and rather small compared to the matrices.  At `size = 1000`, `ArrayFlatten[]` took `0.014-0.015` sec., `ArrayPad[]` took `0.015-0.16` sec., and my method took `0.012-0.014` sec.

My own answer avoids unpacking and uses vectorized functions.  `Outer[Plus, array1, array2]` and `Outer[List, array1, array2]` are extremely efficient special cases of `Outer[]` on packed arrays.

#### Appendix: Timing code

```
sa[size]; // RepeatedTiming                  (* @kglr *)
Table[Which[i == 1, 1, i > j, 1, i == j, -i + 1, True, 0],
   {i, size}, {j, size}]; // RepeatedTiming  (* @Rohit Namjoshi *)
With[{n = size - 1},
 Block[{m1, m2, ones},
  m1 = LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {n, n}], -1];
  m2 = m1 - DiagonalMatrix[Range[n]];
  ones = {ConstantArray[1, n]};
  ArrayFlatten[{{1, ones}, {Transpose@ones, m2}}]
  ]]; // RepeatedTiming                      (* @MikeY *)
With[{r    = Range@size,
      zero = Developer`ToPackedArray@{0}},
   UnitStep[Outer[Plus, r, -r] + PadRight[ConstantArray[r, {1}], {size, size}]] - 
    DiagonalMatrix@PadRight[zero, size, r]
   ]; // RepeatedTiming                      (* @Michael E2 *)
```

Comment: Nice comparison, thanks. I chose my approach more for ease of understanding, or maybe to align with the underlying logic of the matrix, rather than performance. Nice to see it did alright on the performance front too. I learned something!

Comment: Thanks Michael. I think you meant "can be improved by using Array".

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: @MikeY You could also use `ones = ConstantArray[1, {1, n}]` instead of `ToPackedArray`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I tweaked my answer, thanks for the tip.

Comment: My goodness, Mathematica is complicated. Not hating on your answer but ... wow. So many commands!

Comment: @Allure Yeah, consider ``Names["System`*"] // Length``, over 6000 commands, plus many useful undocumented ones.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) as follows

```
sa[n_] := SparseArray[{{i_, i_} /; i > 1 -> 1 - i, {i_, j_} /; 1 < i < j ->  0}, {n, n}, 1]

matrix2 = sa[7] 
matrix2 == matrix
```

> True

Answer (score 9):

One more, for fun and education. Treating it like a block matrix, do the lower right first. This makes a lower triangular matrix of 1s, with the `-1` in the command telling it to make the diagonal = zero.

```
m1=LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {6, 6}], -1]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
m2 = m1 - DiagonalMatrix[Range[6]]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -5 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -6 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now the upper right, a $1 \times 6$ matrix of ones

```
ones = ConstantArray[1, {1, n}]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Use `ArrayFlatten` to get the final answer.

```
ArrayFlatten[{{1, ones}, {Transpose@ones, m2}}]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & -2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & -3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -4 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -5 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -6 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: you can also use `ArrayPad[#, {{1, 0}, {1, 0}}, 1] &`  on `m2` for the last step (+1)

Answer (score 4):

As already suggested in the other answers, vectorization is a key to high performance when working with large numeric arrays. To further increase calculation speed it is useful to remove unnecessary intermediate steps, because memory operations on large arrays can be quite time consuming. Here is a vectorized function with very few intermediate steps:

```
mFast[n_] := LowerTriangularize[DiagonalMatrix[-Range[n]] + 1] + UnitVector[n, 1];
```

Timing measurement:

```
RepeatedTiming[mFast[100];]
```

> {0.000032, Null}

This can be compared to MichaelE2's function:

```
mMichaelE2[size_] := With[{r = Range@size, zero = Developer`ToPackedArray@{0}},
    UnitStep[Outer[Plus, r, -r] + PadRight[ConstantArray[r, {1}], {size, size}]]
    - DiagonalMatrix@PadRight[zero, size, r]];

RepeatedTiming[mMichaelE2[100];]
```

> {0.000047, Null}